# Cakephp contains association when using matching()

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In my project I have the following tables: `Messages`, `Recipients`, `Groups` and `Users`. A `Message` has many `Recipients`, and a `Recipient` has one `Group` and one `User`.

In my `RecipientsTable::beforeFind` I have some code to automatically contain `Groups` and `Users` for `Recipient` finds, since I always need to access those associations.

```
public function beforeFind($event, $query, $options, $primary) {
    return $query->contain([
        'Groups',
        'Users',
    ]);
}
```

I don't know if this is a bad design decision but it has worked for me so far.

The problem has come now that I'm trying to filter messages by group, and I tried doing so by using the `matching` function:

```
$possible_groups = [1,2,3]; //just an example
$query->matching('Recipients', function($q) use ($possible_groups){
            return $q->where(['Recipients.group_id IN' => $possible_groups]);
});
```

When I execute the query, I get the following error:

```
Messages is not associated with Groups
```

Is there any way to keep my beforeFind like that and be able to use matching? Or, is there a better way to automatically load associations without using beforeFind?

TL;DR: A hasMany B, B hasOne C. If a query on table A uses `matching` on table B and table B's beforeFind uses `contain` to load C, C ends up contained onto the original query (of A) and the execution fails since A is not associated with C.

Comment: "is there a better way to automatically load associations without using beforeFind?" Yes

Comment: @Salines, it might be more helpful if you provided some detail on that...

Answer (score 0):

Use table classes to load Table associations automatically. Like using hasMany(), hasOne(), belongsTo(), belongsToMany() in necessary table classes.

Official documentation:
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html

Table files should be in the Table folder inside the Model folder like src\Model\Table.
[image]